# How to add a filter to get_the_author_meta?

Tags: filters

I need to filter calls to get_the_author_meta() but I haven't been able to do it.

I'm using a plugin which uses this function:
get_the_author_meta('display_name', $p->uid)`

I need to be able to filter this funcion and get the uid parameter. But I don't know how to do it.

I've been trying to add a simple filter to the get_the_author_meta() function but I haven't been able to do it. This is what I'm trying now:

```
function get_the_author_meta_filter( $field = '', $user_id = false ) {
    return "Johnn";
}
add_filter( 'get_the_author_meta', 'get_the_author_meta_filter' );
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you [look in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/author-template.php#L116), you'll see the filter applied to `get_the_author_meta` calls:

```
return apply_filters( 'get_the_author_' . $field, $value, $user_id );
```

So your filter should hook `get_the_author_display_name`.